# Cannot update ListView using FirebaseListAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am modifying my simple android app to have chat functionality using [this android tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-android-chat-app-using-firebase--cms-27397). But I am unable to update list view from Firebase real time database. I can write to database but cannot read data and display it.I have tried different solution but it is not working at all.This is my latest code after searching for different solutions and modifying project.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListOptions;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    public DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("message");
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        displayMessage();
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                displayMessage();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }

    public void sendMessage(View v) {
        EditText input = findViewById(R.id.input);
        myRef.push()
                .setValue(new ChatMessage(input.getText().toString(),
                        getUser())
                );
        input.setText("");
        displayMessage();
    }

    private String getUser() throws NullPointerException {
        return FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                .getCurrentUser()
                .getDisplayName();
    }

    private void displayMessage() {
        ListView listOfMessages = findViewById(R.id.list_of_messages);
        FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage> adapter;
        Query query = myRef;
        FirebaseListOptions<ChatMessage> options = new FirebaseListOptions.Builder<ChatMessage>()
                .setQuery(query, ChatMessage.class)
                .setLayout(R.layout.message)
                .build();
        adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<ChatMessage>(options) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, ChatMessage model, int position) {
                TextView messageText = v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
                TextView messageUser = v.findViewById(R.id.message_user);
                TextView messageTime = v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);
                messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
                messageUser.setText(model.getMessageUser());
                messageTime.setText(DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy (HH:mm:ss)",
                        model.getMessageTime()));
            }
        };
        listOfMessages.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

And the JSON file of child message is

```
    {
  "message" : {
    "-L2hcJLFvPY0G1pjj-dY" : {
      "messageText" : "Hi How are you? ",
      "messageTime" : 1515815206276,
      "messageUser" : ""
    },
    "-L2hcKsBwdQX-h_tSHpl" : {
      "messageText" : "It is fine. ",
      "messageTime" : 1515815212543,
      "messageUser" : ""
    },
    "-L2hcMthlhbllagf9d8u" : {
      "messageText" : "Some text for texting",
      "messageTime" : 1515815220832,
      "messageUser" : ""
    }
  }
}
```

As well as ChatMessage.java file code is

```
import java.util.Date;

public class ChatMessage {
    private String messageText;
    private String messageUser;
    private long messageTime;

    public ChatMessage(String messageText, String messageUser) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
        this.messageUser =messageUser;
        messageTime = new Date().getTime();
    }
    public ChatMessage(){

    }
    public String getMessageText() {
        return messageText;
    }

    public String getMessageUser() {
        return messageUser;
    }

    public long getMessageTime() {
        return messageTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show a small snippet of the JSON at `database.getReference().child("message")` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I have added JSON file but for some reason my app was crashing so i have to change some code this JSON is generated by new code only. This code is also not showing ListView at all

Comment: The whole `myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {` on `onCreate` is useless right now, so I'd first remove that to both simplify your actual code and the question. Aside from that I don't immediately see what's going wrong. Is your `populateView` method being called (you can easily test that by setting a breakpoint in it and running the code in the debugger)?

Comment: Now this is a wild guess but I've noticed your `ChatMessage` variables are private. Can you add public setters for these?

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes a public getter *should* be enough, but it's indeed worth a shot.